# Getting error in showing activity via Fragment

Tags: java, android

I am trying to show one my pages in fragments but it is giving me an error.

I have created a separate Class file called FragmentContacts.java, from where i show the layout of activity_contacts.xml.

FragmentContacts Java Code:

```
package me.example.app;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

public class FragmentContacts extends FragmentActivity {

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Get the view from fragmenttab1.xml
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_contacts, container, false);
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
       // setUserVisibleHint(true);
    }

}
```

Fragment Code:

```
public Fragment getItem(int arg0) {
                // getItem is called to instantiate the fragment for the given page.
                // Return a DummySectionFragment (defined as a static inner class
                // below) with the page number as its lone argument.
                //Fragment fragment = new DummySectionFragment();
                //Bundle args = new Bundle();
                //args.putInt(DummySectionFragment.ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, position + 1);
                //fragment.setArguments(args);
                //return fragment;

                switch (arg0) {

                // Open FragmentTab1.java Error on return fragmenttab1
                case 0:
                    FragmentContacts fragmenttab1 = new FragmentContacts();
                    return fragmenttab1;


                return null;
            }
```

Comment: It's not giving you `an error`.  It's giving you something very specific.  No one here is a wizard.  What's the error?

Comment: Just resolved it. I created Fragment separately, and now it working. Thanks

Comment: You should either delete the question, or post what you did to resolve the issue as an answer then accept that answer.

Comment: Sorry just posted it. Forgot to post it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Resolved!

This what I did:
1) I made Fragment Class separately for each tab.
2) Then i used the case in order to show each activity in their respective tab.

(sorry for my lack of technical words.)

Solution:

```
package me.example.app;

import java.util.Locale;

import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class HomeActivity extends FragmentActivity implements
        ActionBar.TabListener {

    /**
     * The {@link android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter} that will provide
     * fragments for each of the sections. We use a
     * {@link android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter} derivative, which
     * will keep every loaded fragment in memory. If this becomes too memory
     * intensive, it may be best to switch to a
     * {@link android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter}.
     */
    SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;
    /**
     * The {@link ViewPager} that will host the section contents.
     */
    ViewPager mViewPager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);

        // Set up the action bar.
        final ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

        // Create the adapter that will return a fragment for each of the four
        // primary sections of the app.
        mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(
                getSupportFragmentManager());

        // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
        mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

        // When swiping between different sections, select the corresponding
        // tab. We can also use ActionBar.Tab#select() to do this if we have
        // a reference to the Tab.
        mViewPager
                .setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                        actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
                    }
                });

        // For each of the sections in the app, add a tab to the action bar.
        for (int i = 0; i < mSectionsPagerAdapter.getCount(); i++) {
            // Create a tab with text corresponding to the page title defined by
            // the adapter. Also specify this Activity object, which implements
            // the TabListener interface, as the callback (listener) for when
            // this tab is selected.
            actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab()
                    .setText(mSectionsPagerAdapter.getPageTitle(i))
                    .setTabListener(this));
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.home, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(ActionBar.Tab tab,
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
        // When the given tab is selected, switch to the corresponding page in
        // the ViewPager.
        mViewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(ActionBar.Tab tab,
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(ActionBar.Tab tab,
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
    }

    /**
     * A {@link FragmentPagerAdapter} that returns a fragment corresponding to
     * one of the sections/tabs/pages.
     */
    public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int arg0) {
            // getItem is called to instantiate the fragment for the given page.
            // Return a DummySectionFragment (defined as a static inner class
            // below) with the page number as its lone argument.    
            switch (arg0){
            case 0:
                Fragment fragmentContacts = new FragmentContacts();
                return fragmentContacts;
            case 1:
                Fragment fragmentMissed = new FragmentMissed();
                return fragmentMissed;
            case 2:
                Fragment fragmentRecent = new FragmentRecent();
                return fragmentRecent;
            case 3:
                Fragment fragmentGroups = new FragmentGroups();
                return fragmentGroups;
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            // Show 4 total pages.
            return 4;
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            Locale l = Locale.getDefault();
            switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return getString(R.string.title_section1).toUpperCase(l);
            case 1:
                return getString(R.string.title_section2).toUpperCase(l);
            case 2:
                return getString(R.string.title_section3).toUpperCase(l);
            case 3:
                return getString(R.string.title_section4).toUpperCase(l);
            }
            return null;
        }
    }


    /**Contacts*/
    public static class FragmentContacts extends Fragment {
        /**
         * The fragment argument representing the section number for this
         * fragment.
         */
        public static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

        public FragmentContacts() {
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_contacts,
                    container, false);
            return rootView;
        }
    }

    /**Missed Call*/
    public static class FragmentMissed extends Fragment {
        /**
         * The fragment argument representing the section number for this
         * fragment.
         */
        public static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

        public FragmentMissed() {
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_missed,
                    container, false);
            return rootView;
        }
    }

    /**Recent Call*/
    public static class FragmentRecent extends Fragment {
        /**
         * The fragment argument representing the section number for this
         * fragment.
         */
        public static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

        public FragmentRecent() {
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_recent,
                    container, false);
            return rootView;
        }
    }

    /**Groups*/
    public static class FragmentGroups extends Fragment {
        /**
         * The fragment argument representing the section number for this
         * fragment.
         */
        public static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

        public FragmentGroups() {
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_group,
                    container, false);
            return rootView;
        }
    }


}
```